# $\bigwedge^nT^∗M$ is trivial $\Leftrightarrow M$ is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, orientation

I can't figure out how to prove the following:

Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold. Then

$\bigwedge^nT^∗M$ is trivial $\Leftrightarrow M$ is orientable

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The bundle is one-dimensional, and such a thing is trivial iff it has a nonzero section.  Now a nonzero section of that bundle is precisely what is known as a volume form, and a manifold is orientable iff it has a volume form.